# Running FlexUnit4 tests in Hudson with ant

Tags: ant, continuous-integration, hudson, flex4, flexunit

I'm just starting to try figure out how to go about continuous integration and test driven development, specifically in Flex 4.

I'd like to run FlexUnit4 tests from an ant script initiated in Hudson. I can get hudson to compile my app but how do I then go about running/seeing results of my tests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did get this working, based on these answers I got from over on the adobe forums:

http://forums.adobe.com/thread/504046?tstart=0

http://forums.adobe.com/thread/505090?tstart=0

Answer (score 1):

We run our flash/flex tests on hudson by using the command-line AIR test runner that is running a wrapped version of our flash/flex test application and having that write out a file in the jUnit file format. Hudson can make a nice visualisation if you use that format.

If you are on a linux host you've got to remember to set up Xvfb to give AIR a 'screen', otherwise it will not work.

Google 'hudson air unittest' or for example http://www.subotnik.com/blog/?p=100 for more.

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to actually run the test... how do I launch the air app? (Total noob here)

Comment: Launch the AIR app using adl, the air debug launcher. See: http://thunderheadxpler.blogspot.com/2008/04/flexunit-ant-air.html for more info.

Answer (score 0):

One of the developers from the FlexUnit4 team has suggested [a solution using ant/maven](http://forums.adobe.com/message/2303179#2303179) on the adobe forums. I'm trying this out now.